# QLPreviewController Fail To Load Large PDF File

Tags: ios, pdf, qlpreviewcontroller

I have tried for almost 2 days but unable to find any solution. I am doubtful whether it's a bug, but not sure.

I have downloaded some pdf files in my documents directory. I can view most of these files with `QLPreviewController`; however, when I try to open one especially large file (almost ~250 MB), `QLPreviewController` only shows the title of file with its size. Don't know how, but ONLY ONCE while debugging the issue it successfully loaded this file.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you looked at similar questions like these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620359/qlpreviewcontroller-crashes-when-trying-to-preview-big-files, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860794/issues-trying-to-preview-big-files-with-qlpreviewcontroller?

Comment: Thanks @Chonch for pointing at this discussion. According to this, I came to the conclusion that its because of memory the large pdf file taking for loading. So need to use 'Atomic Tools' for this. But unfortunately I am developing in Non-ARC environment. More Trouble...

Comment: Isn't there any way to display such kind of large files ?

Comment: Have you tried using a WebView?

Comment: @MichaelL Yes, but Webview too giving me memory warning and crash. And yes, I finally solved the issue. I have used [Reader](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) component which is way too easy and handy to use without memory warning and any crash. Even if I open my pdf in iPads native app and try to back and forth multiple pages for couple of seconds, it crashes, but my app using this component won't. Thanks Reader. Saved me !!